# Complexity of checking whether linear equations have a positve solution

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, linear-algebra, linear-equations

Consider a system of linear equations $Ax=0$, where $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix with rational entries. Assume that the rank of $A$ is $<n$. What is the complexiy to check
whether it has a solution $x$ such that all entries of $x$ are stricly greater than 0 (namely, $x$ is a positive vector)? Of course, one can use Gauss elimination, but this seems not to be optimal.

Comment: Simultaneously crossposted on [CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1500/complexity-of-checking-whether-linear-equations-have-a-positive-solution). Please don't do this, it makes your question seem more important than others.

Comment: I suspect that this is as hard as an arbitrary linear programming problem, which means that you cannot solve it just by using Gaussian elimination. If the rank is exactly $n$, then Gaussian elimination works, but whether you can solve it faster is an interesting question.

Comment: It appears that you have crossposted this question *simultaneously*. While we don't mind a question being reposted, our [site policy](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/231/) only permits a repost after sufficient time has passed and you have not obtained the desired answer elsewhere. I am closing the question since simultaneous crossposting duplicates effort and fractures discussion. Please wait a few days and then if your question is still not answered request a reopening by flagging the question for moderator attention (after summarizing relevant discussions from other sites).